# "Spherical Plot" of a 2D function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, graphing-functions, 3d, spherical-coordinates

I'have seen this graph of a 2D function of $\theta$ and  $\phi$ (let's call it $F(\theta,\phi)$):

[image]

You may see that it's not represented as a conventional surface plot. In fact, there aren't $\theta$ and  $\phi$ on x and y axes, but there is $\theta$ at both x and y axis. Along x axis we have $F(\theta,\phi=0°)$, along y axis we have $F(\theta,\phi=90°)$.

Which kind of graph is this? If I plot $F(\theta,\phi=90°)$ with respect to $\theta,\phi$, I get a completely different result.

I need some formal clarifications about it so that I can make a similar graph on MATLAB or other tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a Cartesian plot of a scalar function $F(\theta, \phi)$ with
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x &= \frac{\theta}{2 \pi} \cos \phi \\
y &= \frac{\theta}{2 \pi} \sin \phi \\
z &= F(\theta, \phi) \\
\end{aligned} \right .$$
If
$$\begin{array}{rccl}
0 & \le & F(\theta, \phi) & \le & 1 \\
0 & \le & \theta & \lt & 2 \pi \\
0 & \le & \phi & \lt & 2 \pi \\
\end{array}$$
then
$$\begin{array}{rccl}
-1 & \le & x & \le & 1 \\
-1 & \le & y & \le & 1 \\
 0 & \le & x^2 + y^2 & \le & 1 \\
 0 & \le & z & \le & 1 \\
\end{array}$$